# Adapt image to text vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a text and an image. These must be adapted to a parent, to who I define a height, for example 100px

The text have to fill what it need. It can be a simple phrase or a long paragraph, for this i can't define a fixed height.

With the remaining space, I want to put a img, but when i put it, the images take the original img height size. You can see my snippet here:

```css
.parent{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
}
.parent img {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.parent .textContainer{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
    <div class="textContainer">Text or html here</div>
</div>
```

Basically, what happens is that the image takes the height that the base image has, that is, if the image is 700px high, it takes 700px high and it goes out of the div, positioning itself as if it were positioned at absolute (it isn't ).

Comment: Welcome Jordi to our community. Thank you for your question. Please, understand that we are all trying to help others and therefore we need very clear problem description. From what I have read so far, I am not able to fully understand, what you are planning to realize. Maybe you should try a translator like http://www.deepl.com to explain your problem in plain english. That might be a good starting point. So, please edit your question. The members will be grateful.

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski I think now is better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your concern correctly, what im going to do in this case is im going to set a max width and height for the  then add width: 100% in the image.. for example

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class="image-style" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
    <div class="textContainer">Text or html here</div>
</div>

.parent{
   height: 100px;
   width: calc(100% - 20px);
   padding: 10px;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
}

.image-style{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  //add more styles if you want
}
```

Comment: With your code if you see, if you inspect element the text is out the parent div. The image should adapt to text. If text needs 80px of height, the image should have 20px of height only. So, its not what I need

Comment: ohhh i see, so  instead of px. you can go % percantage then add another div for the image then add a new class to put the 20% in the image then 80% for the text.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but i have flexible text, for example if i have one phrase i just need 10px and if i have a pharagraph maybe i need 80px. I want to do a flexible flexbox but with image.

Comment: you dont have to worry about the text, because if im doing this, im going to set a width and height for the text then add word-break:break word; so that if the text goes over the max width, it will automatically break it to next line, i dont think setting an exact px for the text alone is a good practice